# How can i say "you can only upload image or video in a post"?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

How can i tell user that they can upload a video OR image in a single post?
My sentence:
`You can only upload image or video for a post`

Comment: Use either-or? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/either-or

Comment: @michael.hor257k i would like to have a full sentence as an answer to be sure that there is no errors.

Comment: Expand your question to a full sentence first.

Comment: @michael.hor257k done

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you mean, you might have to go as far as to say *You may upload only one attachment with each post: one image or one video; not one of each and not more than one of either.*

If that’s what you’re trying to say, and you want every User to understand it, your sentence will in all likelihood be that complicated.